# Excluding a specific file extension from jacoco using sbt

Tags: scala, sonarqube, sbt, jacoco

I am trying to exclude specific file extension from the raport of jacoco.  According to the documentation: https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-jacoco/settings.html I have to specify
jacocoExcludes. So I did it in that way:

jacocoExcludes in Test := Seq(
"**/*.sh"
)

but that does not work... I can still any .sh files in raport of jacoco and then in sonar.

How can I receive that?

Comment: There seems to be an open issue about this in the sbt jacoco GithHub repository: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jacoco/issues/117

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [this issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jacoco/issues/117), the correct method of specifying exclusions in jacoco-sbt is with the `jacocoExcludes` variable. For example:

```scala
jacocoExcludes := Seq(
  "com.test.base.model.TestModel.*"
)
```

Note that this variable supports glob patterns to ignore a package or specific files under the package.